# Joomla access state variable in modules

Tags: variables, joomla, session-variables

How can I access my state variables in Joomla modules?

Usually I do it like

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$variable = $app->getUserState('com_mycomponent.view.filter.variable' ,'default');
```

But in the module the result will be empty or in this case it will be the default value.

In the module there is a selection field. I need to store the input of the selection, to show the selected value again after submitting the page. Without that, the selection field will be reseted after submitting the page.

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ok, thanks! Question is now available under http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4801/joomla-access-state-variable-in-modules